# Most efficient way to find an element in a 2-dim array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, big-o

I'm using polynomial O(n^2) runtime to find all 1s. However, this approach would suffer if my 2 dimensional grow real big. It's going to eat up time. What algorithm should be used and can you refactor the code?

```
function findAllOnes(input) {
  var s = '';
  locationsOfOnes = [];
  for (var y = 0; y < input.length; y++) {
    s = '';
    for (var x = 0; x < input[0].length; x++) {
      s = s + input[y][x].toString(); // this is just for output to show it in 2 dimensional view
      if (input[y][x] !== 0) {
        locationsOfOnes.push({x: x, y: y})
      }
    }
    console.log(y.toString() + '.)', s)
  }
  return locationsOfOnes;
}
```

You can use this live working code - https://jsfiddle.net/tLpa1f3s/

Comment: How is this exponential runtime? this is polynomial runtime O(n^2)

Comment: oh, thanks for correcting me. I'll update it

Comment: This is not even O(n^2), but only O(n). "n" is the input size, which already is the number of all elements. All you can do to improve something, is resolving `var tmp = input[y];` in the outer loop in order to avoid the repeated lookup in the inner loop. Your debug output is also quite expensive.

Comment: Is data random? sorted? anything else that can help us?

Comment: I'm now confused :) Which runtime is it really? Earlier I wrote "exponential" then I was corrected that it should be polynomial runtime. I like your idea regarding tmp.

Comment: @Ext3h, it is O(n^2), because it is n x n, that is you check n rows n times

Comment: SDhaliwa1, the data is what we see in the jsfiddle I posted. It's not random. I mean, it can be random if I assign "1" to a place I like. But sorting should definitely not be done as it will affect coordinates.

Comment: Do you know if the array will be mostly sparse? As in the number of 0's >> number of 1's?

Comment: the number of 0's and 1's can be like "0000000" or "1111100" or "1111111" or "1100101". The length can also be huge like 1,000 zeros or 5,000 1's.

Comment: @sdhaliwal1 Read the code carefully. Each line is only iterated over once, so each **element** is only accessed a constant number of times. "n" is still defined as the number of elements in the matrix, not the number of rows or columns. If it was actually O(n^2), we would have at least two more loops.

Comment: Sure @dawit, please paste gist. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done better than O(n^2) since you would have to travel traverse the array at least once in order to get where the value is equal to one.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait for other inputs. Thanks marvel308.

Comment: This is the correct answer from the information you have given. The array will have to have each value looked at at least one time, as you've computed above.

Comment: Gotcha! I made minor changes by caching the length. It might help in huge dimensions - https://jsfiddle.net/tLpa1f3s/1/